# Programmatically set log4j to System.out

Tags: java, log4j

I want to initialize a logger to simply write to the console.

E.g. (incorrect code)

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(System.out);
logger.debug("test") //prints to System.out
```

Comment: Which version of log4j?

Comment: Down-vote from me - doesn't really seem like you've researched this to any great extent.

Comment: @Duncan Even my google-fu fails sometimes. And the question is not a duplicate because I am not asking about using ConsoleAppenders. I am solving a task, which is achieved using ConsoleAppenders. I cannot google the solution if I do not know what it is.

Comment: @TheRealKingK You're right,not a good duplicate. Retracted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a ConsoleAppender to the logger at Runtime. The following link details this:
http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/08/how-to-programmatically-configure-appenders-in-log4j/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apachi Logger or Java util logger then you should need to know this that getLogger() method is not taking any class object as argument.

[Apachi Logger](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Logger.html)   for print on console - See Console Appender.

[Java Util Logger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html)

Comment: I think OP is using log4j.